# How do I drop certain amount of seconds in VirtualDub?

Tags: virtualdub

It seems the simplest thing you can do with video -- crop space or time dimensions. There is a video how to crop the spacial dimensions (although null transform filter does not seem to crop the selected region for me). Now, I want to drop first n seconds of my video. How do I do that with the notorious editor?

Comment: Cut and trim are the common terms for temporal cropping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the timeline slider to the start point you want and set the Mark In point. The Mark In/Out buttons are to the left of the frame count display at the bottom.

Comment: `Mark in point`? Whatever. I have realized that what I need is called `to cut a video` and this is done using [Edit -> Set selection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldu61L32N2w&feature=youtu.be&t=70).